# Using a single constructor union type

Tags: elm

In Elm, I sometimes find myself defining a record type by using a union type with only a single constructor. I then use a case-statement with only a single case to unpack the record fields:

```
type Model =
    Model { stack: List Int }

update msg model =
    case model of
        Model { stack } ->
            ...
```

Is there a shorter way to unpack this? The single-case case looks kind of silly. It causes unnecessary indentation and verbosity.

Also: I'm using `type` instead of `type alias` to be more explicit when dealing with the central data structures in a program (which tend to have few fields and be used in only a few places in the program, so the extra  verbosity is not *that* much of a problem). Would it be better style to just give up on this approach and use a type alias for records whenever possible?

Comment: As Chad notes below, your wrapping of the Model in a type constructor is not particularly necessary. Its more common among library writers than in those writing apps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pattern match in the function signature itself:

```elm
update msg (Model model) =
    model.stack ...
```

or, if you want to use `stack` directly:

```elm
update msg (Model { stack }) =
    ...
```

As for whether you *should* do this type of thing? I've used it in the past when explicitly trying to hide implementation details from a model. You just have to be willing to deal with the extra verbosity that it inevitably introduces. It really is up to you to decide whether it is necessary. I would probably lean towards avoiding it unless there's an explicit need.